# cant't run the follorwing Query Clause query shows an error message in goormide

Tags: mysql, sql

Running a query that has similar syntax:

```
WITH table1 
AS 
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM photos
),
table2 AS (
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
users
)

SELECT table1 / table2;
```

I'm getting the following error, but not sure why? Really new to SQL. Thanks !

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1 AS

Comment: Think about it, `table1` and `table2` are Common **table** expressions, not columns. You don't divide a CTE by another; they aren't scalar values. You would be better off with 2 subqueries here.

Comment: Fanciful... assign aliases to counts and reference them in main query

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` return? You need to use version 8.0 to use `WITH ...` syntax. Earlier versions do not support CTE.

Comment: @BillKarwin I run this and it shows  5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, I guess it doesn't support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the CTE syntax because you are using MySQL Server 5.7. CTE is a new feature introduced in MySQL 8.0.

But you don't need it for the query you show. You can do it this way:

```
SELECT table1.count / table2.count
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM photos) AS table1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users) AS table2;
```